# Macintosh Color Classic won't turn on and has weird boot chimes

Tags: mac, startup, hardware, classic-mac-os

I recently got my hands on a Macintosh Color Classic that is known to not work in the hope of fixing it. I have the power plugged in, keyboard, and mouse. When I flip the switch on the back, I hear the fan come on, and then three monotone chimes about a second apart. I have searched for manuals or docs to tell me what these chimes mean, because they aren't the normal Sad or Happy Mac chimes. After those chimes, the fan remains on but the screen stays dark. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly the "chimes of death."

If you feel comfortable doing so, pull the motherborard, and try it with different RAM configurations. Look for capacitors with swollen tops (little cylinders) and possibly even replace the PRAM battery.

The board itself could be toast but that should get you started on what to try.

Comment: detail can be found here:
http://vintageapple.org/macbooks/pdf/Troubleshooting_Your_Macintosh_1992.pdf
(page 102)

Comment: Related video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qG7id0RGHoM

Comment: I found some videos of the "chimes of death" and I'm definitely not hearing that. The chimes of death is an arpeggio, and I hear 3 monotone beeps. It looks like there is corrosion on the board (see image here: https://imgur.com/a/pyl38). I will try to clean it with isopropyl alcohol. The fact that it turns on gives me hope!

Comment: Don't use alcohol! Go to an electronics supply store (or Radio Shack if there is still one near you) and get some "Contact Cleaner" that stuff is designed to clean electronics and evaporates FAST. Alcohol does not and it contains water and should be avoided except when moistening a Q-Tip to rub some grease or oil off something.